# What DLL to reference in C# PInvoke for CRegObject methods?

Tags: c#, pinvoke, dllimport

What DLL do I need to reference to access FilerRegister method(s) of the CRegObject from C#?

```
    [DllImport("ATL90.DLL")]
    public static extern int FileRegister(string fileName);
```

And how would I do that in visual studio?

Any help is greatly appreciated! I can't seem to find the correct DLL. I looked on pinvoke.net, but couldn't find it.

Thanks!

Comment: @Dean thanks, basically, I need to register com .rgs files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't. P/Invoke only works with C APIs, it does not work with C++ APIs. Besides, that particular API is implemented in inline C++, it's not actually included in the ATL DLL.

I believe the best you could do is write a C++/CLI wrapper and call *that* from the C# code. Or take the C++ source code (which is included with Visual Studio) and rewrite it in C#.

If you include more details about *why* you want to call `FileRegister`, then maybe there are other alternatives...

Comment: Thanks for enlightening me to to this.